# Como inserir uma nova div e empilhá-las após clicar em um botão

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma div HTML que exibe totais de um cálculo, e preciso que cada vez que seja gerada uma nova (no clique do botão Gerar) uma nova div em branco seja criada para receber os valores, empilhando as já geradas uma embaixo da outra.

**Código HTML**

**BOTAO**

```
<input type="button" value="Gerar Lote" />
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="l1">
    <h4>Resumo</h4>
</div>

<div class="l25">
    <label>Débitos</label>
    <input value="0.00" />
</div>

<div class="l25">
    <label>Créditos</label>
    <input value="0.00" />
</div>
```

Comment: Vc quer gerar só uma div em branco cada vez que clicar no botão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar copias dos elementos que já possui pode utilizar a função [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). Tendo as cópias em mão precisa apenas de as colocar no local certo, que seria no fim de todas as outras que já tem. Consegue fazer isso utilizando a função [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), especificando o elemento de referência como o pai, e indicando `null` como nó de referência.

Exemplo:

```js
const resumo = document.querySelector(".l1");
const [debitos, creditos] = [...document.querySelectorAll(".l25")];

//definir o código para o evento de click no botão gerar
document.getElementById("gerar").addEventListener("click", () => {

  //clonar os 3 divs
  const novoResumo = resumo.cloneNode(true); //true indica cópia profunda
  const novoDebito = debitos.cloneNode(true);
  const novoCredito = creditos.cloneNode(true);
  
  //inserir no fim por ordem cada um dos divs clonados
  resumo.parentNode.insertBefore(novoResumo, null);
  resumo.parentNode.insertBefore(novoDebito, null);
  resumo.parentNode.insertBefore(novoCredito, null);
});
```

```html
<!-- adicionei o id gerar para ficar mais simples -->
<input id="gerar" type="button" value="Gerar Lote" />

<div class="l1">
    <h4>Resumo</h4>
</div>

<div class="l25">
    <label>Débitos</label>
    <input value="0.00" />
</div>

<div class="l25">
    <label>Créditos</label>
    <input value="0.00" />
</div>
```

Funcionalidades utilizadas que pode querer aprofundar:

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [*Destructuring Assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Obrigado Isac, funcionou perfeitamente.