# Reinserindo elementos em outra parte do Body, html e Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou tentando armazenar em uma var, e depois reinserir no body 3 elementos do tipo "**p**".

```
<body>

<p> Um</p>
<p> Dois </p>
<p> Tres </p> ....
```

Ao fazer isso:

```
<script>
    var parag = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        document.write(parag);
</script>
```

O que eu tenho impressos na tela é uma espécie de "rótulo" ou nome da lista de objetos(para o DOM, ou elementos, pro html, correto?) "**p**":

Imprime assim:

**[object NodeList]**

Agora, tem como eu buscar esses elementos "**p**", e efetivamente reimprimir na body o seu conteúdo??

Comment: `querySelectorAll` devolve um `NodeList` logo para utilizar cada um dos elementos precisa de um `for`. Respondi à bem pouco tempo a uma questão muito semelhante à sua se não mesmo duplicada. [Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290025/como-inserir-uma-nova-div-e-empilh%C3%A1-las-ap%C3%B3s-clicar-em-um-bot%C3%A3o/290043#290043)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar `document.querySelectorAll` irá gerar um objeto com uma coleção de nós (*nodes*) dos elementos selecionados no seletor, no seu caso o `"p"` (tag `<p>`).

Para reimprimi-los usando `document.write` você pode usar um laço `for` pegando o HTML de cada item da coleção com `outerHTML`. Existem outras formas de inserir os itens na página, mas usando `document.write` poderia ser desta forma:

```js
var parag = document.querySelectorAll("p");

for(var x=0; x<parag.length; x++){
   document.write(parag[x].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p> Um</p>
<p> Dois </p>
<p> Tres </p>
```

Você pode também clonar os elementos e ir reinserindo na página usando o método `cloneNode`:

```js
var parag = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for(var x=0; x<parag.length; x++){
   var clone = parag[x].cloneNode(true); // true quer dizer selecionar tudo do elemento
   document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<p> Um</p>
<p> Dois </p>
<p> Tres </p>
```